# Is a monotone class which is closed under complements and finite disjoint unions a sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $M$ be a monotone class over a set $X$. Suppose that $M$ is:

1. Closed under complements.
2. Closed under **finite disjoint** unions.

> Is it true that $M$ is a sigma-algebra?

Does anything change if we add the assumption that $M$ is closed under **countable disjoint** unions?

Note that there is a monotone class which is closed under complements, but not a sigma-algebra: The collection of all unbounded intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

However, this example is not closed under finite disjoint unions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If $M$ is too small (i.e., empty) or too large (i.e., not a set) then it is not a $\sigma$-algebra.  But those are trivial cases.  Here is a less pathological counterexample:

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and
$$M=\big\{\emptyset,\;\;\{1,2\},\;\;\{2,3\},\;\;\{3,4\},\;\;\{1,4\},\;\;\{1,2,3,4\}\big\}$$
Then $M$ is a monotone class closed under complements and finite disjoint unions, but not under intersections.

Comment: How do you know that $M$ is closed under intersections?

Comment: A monotone class by definition is closed under intersections.

Comment: A monotone class is only required to be closed under countable _monotone_ intersections. @BenW

Comment: Oops!  Fixed it.